# Switch Songs | Automatically | after pre-defined time

Tags: vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

Is it possible to configure any player to **play songs only for defined time and then switch** automatically to other song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is typically called "Intro." I found a [Winamp Plugin](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/gen-intro/4039) with some Google-fu. Some other media players have this built-in.

Answer (score 0):

[Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/download) together with its component [foo_skip](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_skip) can do this too

> The component also offers functionality to skip only parts of a track. To utilize the partial skipping set a tag field SKIP with timecodes that you want skipped. For example SKIP=0:00:00-0:01:25 (or simply SKIP=-0:01:25) to skip the first 85 seconds.

```
Can also skip parts of tracks. Tag field SKIP specifies the timecodes:
SKIP=-<time>    to skip from the beginning to <time>
SKIP=<time>-    to skip from <time> to the next track
SKIP=<a>-<b>    to skip from position <a> to later position <b>
SKIP=-<a>;<b>-  to skip from start to <a> and from <b> to next track
```

For example the value `00:03:00-` will skip all tagged files after 3 minutes. Note the ending minus. Read more on [hydrogenaudio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=30361&st=240) on how to set it up. It's a little bit tricky